# How would you rephrase this to be in passive voice?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

> We gave the teacher a few gifts and a card.

This confuses me because I can see the teacher receiving the action of being given something, but also the gifts and card receiving the action of being given away

This is how I presume it might be:

> A few gifts and a card were given to the teacher by us.

Comment: That's perfectly grammatical and a passivisation of the original, as is 'The teacher was given a few gifts and a card by us' (though without context, neither sounds as natural as the original).

Comment: Thanks! What I want to know though is what is the technical object of the original sentence. Probably should've specified I wanted an equivalent of the sentence

Comment: [We] [S] / gave [the teacher] [IO] /  [a few gifts and a card] [DO].

Comment: In the case of ditransitive verbs, it's the Oi of the active that usually corresponds to the subject of the passive. Thus the passive equivalent of your example would be "The teacher was given a few gifts and a card by us".

Comment: You are right. Grammar doesn't determine the intent of an uttering. The passivisation depends on the original reading. It's possible both ways (See @EdwinAshworth above).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth See above.

Comment: @BillJ what is an Oi?

Comment: @Kris what do you mean by intent? I thought that to make it passive the object of the active sentence should be first.

Comment: @marigolds Oi = indirect object and Od - direct object.

Comment: @BillJ Do you have a source about indirect objects being the subject in passive? I have never heard that before. Thanks. Also I'm certain the abbreviation used is IO and DO

Comment: @marigolds Subscript, subscript! Note the capitalization.

Comment: @Kris I don't know what you mean ?? A subscript is printed below a line

Comment: Nevermind, just think of it as a subscript and you can see why the order is reversed. Sometimes it may not be possible to display fonts with superscript/ subscript, so authors may prefer to write Vi (input voltage) - Vo (output voltage) to ensure the letters are displayed on all systems.